# Hot swapping in Wildfly-Swarm (now Thorntail)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hotswap, wildfly-swarm, thorntail

We are migrating an old JavaEE microservice to cloud (Openshift), so we are wrapping it into **Wildfly-Swarm** (now Thorntail).

We managed to make it work, optimize fractions and so, but when it comes tu run the project locally we are doing `mvn wildfly-swarm: run` (now from fatjar).

Works well, we keep the packaging to jar and creates a jar with everything it needs and runs. But we can't do hot swapping, hot realoding, whatever you want to call it; dynamically replacing a class implementation during the runtime of an application, change the code without re-running the server. And we want to use **Eclipse IDE**, yes.

I have been googling quite a bit, most useful things I found are on the direction of package the maven project as jar, then it creates a hollowjar which would be the "server part" you need, and then with that somehow you con reload only the code part and everything could work. Tried with little success [Wildfly-hive](https://github.com/fbricon/wildfly-hive#wildfly-hive)

Would be very please if somebody could give us a hand :D

Answer (score 0):

After migrating this to new microprofile implementation Thorntail, now they are about to release native support for hotswapping using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
   <artifactId>thorntail-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Springboot's style. This will be there from version 4.0.0 onwards. already gave it a try on SNAPSHOT